# why c# dynamic compiled type cannot be found by using Type.GetType method?

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, dynamic-compilation

```
ICodeCompiler comp = new CSharpCodeProvider().CreateCompiler();
            CompilerParameters cp = new CompilerParameters();
            cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("system.dll");
            cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("system.data.dll");
            cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("system.xml.dll");
            cp.GenerateExecutable = false;
            cp.GenerateInMemory = true;
            StringBuilder codes = new StringBuilder();
            codes.Append("using System; \n");
            codes.Append("using System.Data; \n");
            codes.Append("namespace Test \n");
            codes.Append("{ \n");
            codes.Append(" public class TestClass \n");
            codes.Append(" { \n");
            codes.Append("    public static string TestMethod() \n");
            codes.Append("     { \n");
            codes.Append("        return ""; \n");
            codes.Append("     } \n");
            codes.Append(" } \n");
            codes.Append("} \n");
            CompilerResults cr = comp.CompileAssemblyFromSource(cp, codes.ToString());
```

after I compiled this class succesfully and used the method by invoke method successfully, I used GetType("Test.TestClass") then return null. what's wrong?

Comment: try `cr.CompiledAssembly.GetType("Test.TestClass")`

Answer (score 0):

`Type.GetType` needs an `AssemblyQualifiedName` to work. However, your compiled assembly has a random name.

Options for you to get the Type are:

1. `cr.CompiledAssembly.GetType`
2. `cr.CompiledAssembly.ExportedTypes`
3. Give your assembly a name by adding

```cs
cp.OutputAssembly =@"C:\my_full_path\myName.dll"
```

then use `Test.TestClass, myName, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null`